Как при компиляции сразу запускать и клиент и сервер
Пишу мессенджер, как только начал разрабатывать - сделал launch.json с конфигом запуска клиента и сервера, и почему-то при ctrl + f5 проект компилировался (клиент и сервер), но запускался только клиент, и приходилось после компиляции еще нажимать f5 чтоб все запустилось.
Сейчас вот решил упростить себе жизнь и сделать так, чтобы при нажатии ctrl + f5 компилировался и сервер и клиент, а после запускался. Искал в аишке, гуглил и на английском, и на русском. В последнем варианте ничего не нашел, а на английском либо я сути не улавливаю, либо там не моя проблема
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Server",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/server/quty-server.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "visualizerFile": "c:\\Users\\blood\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\2e9ca2000cbab501e1a227151fba93d8\\tonka3000.qtvsctools\\qt.natvis.xml"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Client",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/client/quty-client.exe",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "visualizerFile": "c:\\Users\\blood\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\2e9ca2000cbab501e1a227151fba93d8\\tonka3000.qtvsctools\\qt.natvis.xml"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Server", "Client"]
    }]
}


Вам надо сервер и клиент компилировать отдельно,
и прописать сценарий для одновременного запуска обоих
исполняемых файлов.
В Вашей конфигурации клиент и сервер запускаются последовательно.
system("./myProgram &");
//                  ^
//           run in background


мне выдало что в prelaunchtask-е не найдена задача Server. В tasks.json добавил следующее (и изменил Server на Start Server соответственно)
{
            "label": "Start Server",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/build/server/quty-server.exe",
            "group": {
                "kind": "none",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
}

Сервер он запускает, правда vscode ожидает пока задача завершится, и не запускает клиент до этого момента

Во-первых, Вам надо обновить тело вопроса, т.к. изначально в вопросе вы писали: "запускается только  клиент". Во-вторых, Вы уже поработали с проблемой - лучше её понимаете  и сможете детальнее описать. В-третьих, написанное Вами в комментариях читать не удобно.

Я отредактировала ответ, давайте ещё упростим.
